# Is there any method in Kotlin which allow me to translate a value from a range into another range?

Tags: range, kotlin

I have a value inside a range of numbers (for instance `0..100`) which I want to translate it into another range, (for instance to `0..9`). So the result would be:

`50 -> 4` or `100 -> 9`, ...

Is there any method in Kotlin which helps me in this regard?

Comment: I didn't get your idea, what the 51 will be converted to ?

Comment: @KrisRoofe 51 would be 4 until we get to 55 and between 55 to 60 the result would be 5. I somehow want to transfer my range into a new range.

Comment: the new range also have 100 elements?

Comment: what will be 0 convert to ?

Comment: @KrisRoofe the new range is not specific, it may have 20 element (0..19) or 9 elements (0..8)

Comment: @KrisRoofe in question sample 0 -> 0

Comment: If so, `0->0, 50->4, 100->9`, it's a nonlinear convertion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculate the ratio of the number within the original range.
Multiply it by the second range.

```
fun convert(number: Int, original: IntRange, target: IntRange): Int {
    val ratio = number.toFloat() / (original.endInclusive - original.start)
    return (ratio * (target.endInclusive - target.start)).toInt()
}
```

As an extension function

```
fun IntRange.convert(number: Int, target: IntRange): Int {
    val ratio = number.toFloat() / (endInclusive - start)
    return (ratio * (target.endInclusive - target.start)).toInt()
}

val result =  (0..100).convert(50, 0..9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It is correct, just want to know if is there any function in Kotlin API or I have to do this.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could write it as an extension function

Comment: This solution would not work in all cases.
Eg (assuming you do the same for floats) if you have `number = 0.9`, `originalRange = 0.8f to 1f` and `target = 0f to 1f`

Comment: Your answer only works when the original range start value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
val r2 = IntRange(0, 100).filter { it %10 ==0 }.map { it /10 }
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad question, I just improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If your new range does not start from zero, add the first element as below

```
fun mapRange(number: Int, prevRange: IntRange, newRange: IntRange) : Int {
    val ratio = number.toFloat() / (prevRange.last - prevRange.first)
    return (ratio * (newRange.last - newRange.first) + newRange.first).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on Benito's answer, but adjusted for cases when original starting value is not 0.

```
fun convert(number: Int, original: IntRange, target: IntRange): Int {
    val ratio = (number - original.start).toFloat() / (original.endInclusive - original.start)
    return (ratio * (target.endInclusive - target.start)).toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works,

```
val original = 0..100
val new = original.step((original.endInclusive - original.start) / 9).map{it /10}.forEach{ println(it)}
```

output,

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```